# How do fetch specific value from the array of data?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla2.5, session-variables

I am trying to fetch specific data from the array of data but not able to get proper output. Please guide me.

**Code**

```
echo "<pre>";
    $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
    $cmpny=$cart->BT;
    print_r($cmpny);

    $i=0;
    foreach($cmpny as $data)
    {
        if(true)
        {
        echo $data."\n";
        }
        $i++;

    }
    exit;
```

Output What I am Getting

[image: Output What I am Getting]

How could i able to fetch only [company] or only any single element.... i had try to access with

```
 $data->company
```

but not able to fetch.... so please guide me....

Comment: `echo $data["company"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please try this

```
foreach($cmpny as $data)
{          
   echo $data['company']."\n";
}
```

I think you got result as company data

Comment: Why `if(true)` ? That will never be false

Comment: Yes you are right i will take care of it for next time @ØHankyPankyØ

Comment: dear @Ø Hanky Panky Ø i have to write some code in if and perform some operation on company data so at initially i make if (true).. just for testing.......

Comment: @Jalpesh i had try but that was not working....
It displaying me first letter of each element......

Comment: have you modify my code and than after you use it or directly use and get only first letter in result @AnandMehta

Comment: @Jalpesh there is no need to modification because variable and element name are same what i am using. and before put question here i had try that..... and result was what i told you.... get only first letter in result...

Answer (score 5):

You have array as result, so you should use array access instead of property access: `$data['company']`

Answer (score 2):

$data->company can only be used if the $data is an object, to access elements in array, you should use $data['company']